# Integrating confluent kafka-restproxy with AWS MSK

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk, kafka-rest

I am trying to integrate AWS MSK with Confluent provided RestProxy. I hv created the AWS MSK cluster, without authentication for note, and hv deployed the RestProxy provided by confluent on same VPC. After giving the Plaintext zookeeper connection and SSL for bootstrap server on rest proxy , when I am hitting

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8082/V3/clusters
```

I’m getting 404 from rest proxy. If I hit

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8082/
```

The resource responds back with empty json {}

I am not sure I am missing on something.

Comment: What version of the proxy are you running? Case matters, too, so `/v3` (what's in the documentation) would be different from `/V3`

Comment: I’m using confluent.5.1.2-2.11 .. not sure about the version for rest api.. any pointers how we can get it??

Comment: It would match. Did you try the lowercase v3, as mentioned?